# Invoking a webpage using Lambda with node.js

Tags: aws-lambda

I am learning AWS and as part of that I am trying to create a Lambda using node.js.
I am trying to invoke a webpage using the following, please correct me. What I am missing?

```
const opn = require('opn');
opn('http://google.com', {app: 'firefox'});
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your
way arround here. Also I suggest you check how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples. 
These guidelines will help you get better answers in the future. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a post detailing how to set this up if you only want to hit URLs with Lambda. You can find it [here.](https://www.aaronmedacco.com/blog/post/2017/06/04/scheduling-url-requests-w-aws-lambda)

If you already know how to setup IAM permissions and scheduling with CloudWatch, the code I used accomplished this with Node.js 6.10 runtime:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var urls = event.urls;
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var protocol = urls[i].Protocol;
    var domain = urls[i].Domain;
    var queryString = urls[i].QueryString;
    var url = protocol + "://" + domain + queryString;
    if (protocol.toLowerCase() === "http") {
        var j = i;
        http.get(url, function(res) {
            // Get around async.
            var requestUrl = urls[j].Protocol + "://" + urls[j].Domain + urls[j].QueryString;
            console.log("Response from " + requestUrl + ": ");
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            console.log(res.statusMessage);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        });
    } else if (protocol.toLowerCase() === "https") {
        https.get(url, function(res) {
            var j = i;
            // Get around async.
            var requestUrl = urls[j].Protocol + "://" + urls[j].Domain + urls[j].QueryString;
            console.log("Response from " + requestUrl + ": ");
            console.log(res.statusCode);
            console.log(res.statusMessage);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Encountered error: " + e.message);
        });
    }
    // Force break due to async -> output.
    if ((i+1) == urls.length) {
        break;
    }
}
```

};

You would define the URLs you would like to invoke by passing an event object that is similar to the following:

```
{"urls": [{
  "Protocol": "HTTP",
  "Domain": "www.aaronmedacco.com",
  "QueryString": ""}, {
  "Protocol": "HTTPS",
  "Domain": "www.google.com",
  "QueryString": "?key=value"}]}
```

Again, if you want a step by step, check out [this post.](https://www.aaronmedacco.com/blog/post/2017/06/04/scheduling-url-requests-w-aws-lambda) Simple to set up.

Comment: Thanks aton, it was much detailed. I shall try it and get back to you